# Why does the blue tooth low energy scanner need to be restarted again?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I noticed that in a couple implementations of the ble scanner that the scanning is stopped and started again after a given time period, like every 20 seconds.

Here for example here is a scanner class firing up the scanner in a separate thread. You can see in the `start()` method that the thread is put to sleep for a period of time, and the scanner is then stopped and restarted:

```
public class BleScanner extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private final BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback;

    private volatile boolean isScanning = false;

    public BleScanner(BluetoothAdapter adapter, BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback callback) {

        bluetoothAdapter = adapter;
        mLeScanCallback = callback;
    }

    public boolean isScanning() {
        return isScanning;
    }

    public void startScanning() {
        synchronized (this) {
            isScanning = true;
            start();
        }
    }

    public void stopScanning() {
        synchronized (this) {
            isScanning = false;
            bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            // Thread goes into an infinite loop
            while (true) {

                synchronized (this) {

                    // If there is not currently a scan in progress, start one
                    if (!isScanning) break;
                    bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }

                sleep(Constants.SCAN_PERIOD); // Thread sleeps before stopping the scan

                // stop scan
                synchronized (this) {
                    bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }

                // restart scan on next iteration of infinite while loop
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {


        } finally { // Just in case there is an error, the scan will be stopped

            bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

            // The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the
            // finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs.
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any benefits to stopping and restarting the scanner? Why not just let the scan continue perpetually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are advantages. On some devices, you would only see an advertisement from a device once per scan. On some you would see all advertisements. Also, restarting the scan cleans up some low-level stuff and is generally better than keeping the scanner active all the time.